# Printing queue.peek() in Recursion prints irrelevant values

Tags: java, recursion, queue

I am trying to check whether linked list is palindrome using queue.
 
 `solve()` function returns **true** if linked list is palindrome.Equating `q.peek` with Node value returns **false** even after values are equal.
 Tried printing `q.peek()` returns **LList$Node@7852e922**.
 I did google it says like Queue node value is in use in previous functional call, did not get much.

```
public class LList {
    private Node head = null;

    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;

        Node(int d) {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    public void push(int d) {
        Node n = new Node(d);
        n.next = head;
        head = n;
    }

    public boolean solve(Node t, Queue q) {
        if (t == null) {
            return true;
        }

        q.add(t.data);
        if (solve(t.next, q)) {
            **System.out.println(q.peek());**//LList$Node@7852e922
            if (q.peek().equals(t.data)) {
                q.remove();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LList lList = new LList();
        lList.push(5);
        lList.push(4);
        lList.push(3);
        lList.push(4);
        lList.push(5);
        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        System.out.println(lList.solve(lList.head, q));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared Queue for Integer but you are trying to insert Node in the queue. 
Change the comparison `q.peek().equals(t.data)` to `q.peek().data == t.data` and the type of queue to `Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>()`

Working code is(Comments added for the changes made):

```
public class LList {
  //Made head static
  private static Node head = null;

  static class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
  }

  public void push(int d) {
    Node n = new Node(d);
    n.next = head;
    head = n;
  }

  //changed the parameter type to Queue<Integer>
  public boolean solve(Node t, Queue<Integer> q) {
    if (t == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (q == null) {
        q = new LinkedList<>();
    }
    q.add(t.data);
    if (solve(t.next, q)) {
        System.out.println(q.peek()); //prints 5 4 3 4 5
        //changed the comparison condition.
        if (q.peek() == t.data) {
            q.remove();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else
        return false;
    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    LList lList = new LList();
    lList.push(5);
    lList.push(4);
    lList.push(3);
    lList.push(4);
    lList.push(5);
    System.out.println(lList.solve(lList.head, null));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
5
4
3
4
5
true
```

Comment: I have changed the code,q.add(t) was  mistake while coping/modyfying in stackoverflow.If u print q.peek()//which should return int data,instead returning  LList$Node@7852e922

Comment: I have modified my code and `q.peek()` does print data instead of `Node` object. Do look at the changes I have made(explained using comments)

Answer (score 0):

As @Pramod said you adding a Node to queue here: `q.dd(t)`

In this method:

```
public boolean solve(Node t, Queue q) {
    if (t == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (q == null) {
        q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
    q.add(t);
    if (solve(t.next, q)) {
        **System.out.println(q.peek());**//LList$Node@7852e922
        if (q.peek().equals(t.data)) {
            q.remove();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Did you mean to `q.add(t.data)`?